# Spring Boot Jetty 3.0.5 turn off JNDI

Tags: java, spring-boot, jndi

In my gradle base project I'm trying upgrade spring (`spring-boot-starter-jetty`) dependency from 2.7.6 to 3.0.5
And looks everything start up and work fine. However during start up I noticed logs from JNDI loop up.

```
DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.group]
DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.group] not found - trying original name [logging.group]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env is not bound; remaining name 'env/logging.group'
DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.group]
DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [logging.group] threw NamingException with message: null. Returning null.
DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.group]
DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.group] not found - trying original name [logging.group]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env is not bound; remaining name 'env/logging.group'
DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.group]
DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [logging.group] threw NamingException with message: null. Returning null.
DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.level]
DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.level] not found - trying original name [logging.level]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env is not bound; remaining name 'env/logging.level'
DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.level]
DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [logging.level] threw NamingException with message: null. Returning null.
DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.level]
DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.level] not found - trying original name [logging.level]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env is not bound; remaining name 'env/logging.level'
DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.level]
DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [logging.level] threw NamingException with message: null. Returning null.
DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.level.org.springframework]
DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.level.org.springframework] not found - trying original name [logging.level.org.springframework]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env is not bound; remaining name 'env/logging.level.org.springframework'
DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.level.org.springframework]
DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [logging.level.org.springframework] threw NamingException with message: null. Returning null.
DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.level.org.hibernate]
DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.level.org.hibernate] not found - trying original name [logging.level.org.hibernate]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env is not bound; remaining name 'env/logging.level.org.hibernate'
DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.level.org.hibernate]
DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [logging.level.org.hibernate] threw NamingException with message: null. Returning null.
```

As I found to turn off JNDI I should set in spring `application.properties`

> spring.jndi.enabled=false
> and
> org.eclipse.jetty.jndi=false

But it looks like this options doesn't work in spring boot 3 because still I see the JNDI look up logs. Did any one this issue and know how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/39671593/775715 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/55097841/775715